# How to remove outliers from a dataframe?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, outliers

I have a (268X4) df and found the outliers (22,1) for one column. I want to remove those outliers from the df. How do I do that?

```
> df=df_nonull import pandas as pd   # to manipulate dataframes import
> numpy as np   # to manipulate arrays
> 
> # a number "a" from the vector "x" is an outlier if 
> # a > median(x)+1.5*iqr(x) or a < median-1.5*iqr(x)
> # iqr: interquantile range = third interquantile - first interquantile def 
>outliers(x): 
>        return np.abs(x- x.median()) > 1.5*(x.quantile(.75)-
>x.quantile(0.25))
> 
> # Give the outliers for the first column for example 
>outliers=df.StockValue[outliers(df.StockValue)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only remove the whole row, njot a single cell like (22,1). If you want to remove the complete row of the data.

df = df.drop(df.index[[22]])